# Difficulty with the image quality of the map generated with Bing Map Api

Tags: dictionary, localization, geolocation, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm developing an application that retrieves an image of "Bing Maps" with [Bing Api] since my webService.
My problem is the rendering of the image.
**If I set my zoom greater** than 11,**or if I set a size too big**, the result of recover my image is like "cut" into several loading and gives the impression that the image is not entirely downloaded.

**Example picture below...**

Have you any idea why the image looks like its back?

Here is my code used in my webService.

```
    //call function 
    GetImageMap(46,6,800,800,17);

    //Get Bing map Image from the web
    public string GetImageMap(double latitude,double longitude,int mapSizeHeight, int mapSizeWidth, int zoomLevel)
    {
        string key = "asoidfz9aos78fa9w3hf9w3fh9hf7ha9wfw37fhblablablablablabla";
        MapUriRequest mapUriRequest = new MapUriRequest();

        // Set credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        mapUriRequest.Credentials = new ImageryService.Credentials();
        mapUriRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        // Set the location of the requested image
        mapUriRequest.Center = new ImageryService.Location();
        mapUriRequest.Center.Latitude = latitude;
        mapUriRequest.Center.Longitude = longitude;

        // Set the map style and zoom level
        MapUriOptions mapUriOptions = new MapUriOptions();
        mapUriOptions.Style = MapStyle.Aerial;
        mapUriOptions.ZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
        mapUriOptions.PreventIconCollision = true;
        // Set the size of the requested image in pixels
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize = new ImageryService.SizeOfint();
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Height = mapSizeHeight;
        mapUriOptions.ImageSize.Width = mapSizeWidth;

        mapUriRequest.Options = mapUriOptions;

        //Make the request and return the URI
        ImageryServiceClient imageryService = new ImageryServiceClient();
        MapUriResponse mapUriResponse = imageryService.GetMapUri(mapUriRequest);
        return mapUriResponse.Uri;
    }
    // ### END Function getImageMap
```

And the url query:

```
http://api.tiles.virtualearth.net/api/GetMap.ashx?c=46,6&dcl=1&w=800&h=800&b=a,mkt.en-US&z=17&token={token}
```

Result image.. :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to the aerial imagery and it's not technically related. 
I will report it to the appropriate team.

By the way, you should use the REST Imagery API which is the official way to use the imagery from Bing, see the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Here is a sample URL based on your example:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Aerial/46,6/17?mapSize=800,800&key=YOURKEY
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really need to maintain a quality image with the zoom parameters and size. But you called me that the problem does not come from me? And so I can not do anything right now?

Comment: It's not on your side and there's pretty much nothing you can do about it right now. I will report it to the team, if you're a enterprise customer, you can reach the technical support to report this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much if you can do this for me. No unfortunately not. I opened an account yesterday to try to use technology in my bing project before paying a license. I did not work with google maps because all my work is focused on Microsoft technology. I can wait to see if Microsoft will fix this annoying problem before turning to another service ^ ^

Comment: I doubt there is much you can do.  Keep in mind that for satellite imagery, Bing/Google use images from different sources and employ algorithms to stitch the images together into one "seamless" panel.  As such, there will be places where images from different sources collide and you are seeing this.  I.E. for certain zoom levels, two adjacent tiles will be from different sources and will appear differently.

Comment: Actualy, Bing and Google both have internal process to do imagery correction and rectification so the various source of satellite imagery can be integrated into a single pipeline and adjust the different property and the rendered aspect. For aerial imagery (like here), the process is a little bit different but main principles still and this kind of errors recently appeared linked to the last imagery upgrade. As said, I've reported it internaly so the team is aware of this issue on this specific location.